# get input data to email function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to get the input of the user into my email message body I tried $data but no luck. Not sure how I would do it. So basically when user inputs name and email and hit submit they get an email but it comes out blank if I try $data in message. This is part of my controller code were the email section is located

```
//Insert the callin 
    public function  insert_callin()
    { 


    $data=array('name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
            'email'=>$this->input->post('email'));

        //print_r($data);

            $result=$this->callin_model->insert_callin($data); 
            if($result > 0) 
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg',"Callin Record Added Successfully");
            $this->load->library('email');

            $this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
            $this->email->to('donny.ortiz@nordstrom.com'); 

            $this->email->subject('Email Test');
            $this->email->message($data);

            $this->email->send();


            redirect('callin');

        }
        else
        {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg1',"Callin Record Added Failed");
            redirect('callin');


        }
```

Comment: message() accepts string, so you can't send array. Simple create string using $this->input->post('name') and $this->input->post('email')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the code like below....

```
//Insert the callin 
public function  insert_callin()
{ 


    $data=array('name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
        'email'=>$this->input->post('email'));

    $msg_body = "<table>";
    $msg_body .= "<tr>";
    $msg_body .= "<td>Name</td><td>:</td><td>".$data['name']."</td>";
    $msg_body .= "<td>Email</td><td>:</td><td>".$data['email']."</td>";
    $msg_body .= "</tr>";
    $msg_body .= "</table>";

    //print_r($data);

        $result=$this->callin_model->insert_callin($data); 
        if($result > 0) 
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg',"Callin Record Added Successfully");
        $this->load->library('email');

        $this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
        $this->email->to('donny.ortiz@nordstrom.com'); 

        $this->email->subject('Email Test');
        $this->email->message($msg_body);

        $this->email->send();


        redirect('callin');

    }
    else
    {

        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg1',"Callin Record Added Failed");
        redirect('callin');


    }
```

The `$this->email->message` accepts string not an array.

Comment: This is working but coming out like this <table><tr><td>Name</td><td>:</td><td>donny
</td><td>Email</td><td>:</td><td>test@mail.com</td></tr></table>

Comment: @Donny For that you have to set the mail type HTML for set that open ROOT/application/config/email.php and add `$config['mailtype'] = 'html';`

Answer (score 0):

The $this->email->message accepts string and you can serialize array like `$this->email->message(serialize($data));`